# Need some clarification for $\int_{-π/2}^{π/2} \cos t \, dt = 2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\int_{-π/2}^{π/2} \cos t \ dt = 2$$

Though I understand it mechanically, the idea of $F(b) - F(a)$. Conceptually, I'm missing something. If you draw $\sin{x}$ for $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ in the unit circle you end up with half a circle. Since there's a bit of area between the arc and the straight lines connecting $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ and $\pi$ to $-\pi/2$, I wonder what happens with this area.

Comment: You have to draw $\cos (x)$

Comment: Also note that $\cos(x)$ is an even function i.e $\cos(x)=\cos(-x).$ So what you are really finding is double the area under $\cos(x)$ for $x \in [0 ,\frac{\pi}{2} ].$

Comment: Why is it half ellipse then? Shouldnt I use the unit circle for this?

Comment: Conceptually, you are finding the area under the curve $y=\cos(x)$ for $x \in [-\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{\pi}{2}].$ I don't really understand your reference to the unit circle.

Comment: @VivekKaushik What do you mean $\cos x$ is not even a function?

Comment: I said it's an even function. By even, I am talking about parity.  I think you misread the statement.

Comment: Ok its clear now. Somehow I had (sin(x), cos(x)) in myvhead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion. The function $ \cos x $ does not have the same graph as a quadrant of the unit circle.

To see this more clearly, consider the unit circle centred at $ (0,0)$. Then at $ (-1,0)$ the circle has infinite slope (strictly speaking it's undefined, but infinite slope is easier to understand). But at a similar point on the graph of $ \cos x$, by taking the derivative at $ ( -\pi, 0)$ we see that the slope is just $1$, which is considerably different.

So the two shapes are somewhat similar but not the same.

Comment: Yes, somehow I had the graphs of quadrants of the unit circle in my head. Not the graph of y = cos x :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by drawing $\sin x$ in the unit circle, but since $\cos x$ is the rate of change of $\sin x,$ the integral must be the total change in $\sin x$ as $x$ goes from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2.$ And that means going half-way around the unit circle from the lowest point to the highest, and asking what's the total change in the $y$-coordinate.